# Highest number in a list with Racket

Tags: beginner, functional-programming, lisp, racket

I am trying to build a function to find the highest number in a list without using the built-in functions of "apply" and "max".

I created the following code:

```
(define (highest-num lst)
  (define (iter lst accu)
    (cond ((null? lst) accu)
          ((< accu (first lst)) (iter (rest lst) (+ accu (- (first lst) accu))))
          (else (iter (rest lst) accu))))    
  (iter lst 0))
```

However, I bet this could be better. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Remarks

1. Using an internal function, recursion, and a trampoline is a good way to structure recursive procedures on a lists.
2. The code fragment `(+ accu (- (first lst) accu)))` is the same as `(first lst)`.
3. The name `accu` suggests an accumulator, however, the value it stores is the maximum, so `max` might be better.
4. Because of the letter `l` can be confused with `1`, `lst` can be read as slang for 'first'. I prefer `xs` as the name for a list of `x`'s. The nomenclature has become more common in Lisps over the past few decades due to the influence of other functional languages.
5. No matter how it is dressed up, there's a `max` procedure in the code somewhere. And it has to be written. It is better to be explicit about it than to try to hide `max` by embedding it in some other function.

### Alternative

For procedures that try to find a property of a list, folding is often a good place to start. This code uses [`foldl`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=fold#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29). Usually I find `foldl` rather than `foldr` is what I want, for whatever that's worth.

```
#lang racket
(define (highest-number xs)
  (define (max x1 x2)
    (if (> x1 x2) x1 x2))
  (foldl max (first xs) (rest xs)))
```

Maybe it's worth pointing out, that the starting point for writing the `highest-number` was wishful thinking where I wished I had `max`. Then at the next lower level of abstraction down, I wrote it. Credit goes to Ableson and Sussman's [*SICP* lectures.](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8FE88AA54363BC46)

Answer (score 1):

One can also use 'named let' here to have a recursive loop that compares sequentially each item to the maximum till that point:

```
(define (mymax L)
  (let loop ((L (cdr L)) 
             (m (car L)))          ; consider first item to be max at start.
    (cond
      [(empty? L) m]
      [(> (car L) m)               ; if next item is larger, loop with that.
         (loop (cdr L) (car L))]
      [else                        ; else loop with current max.
         (loop (cdr L) m)])))
```